# Time integration for elastodynamics

Tags: time-integration, discontinuous-galerkin

I'd like to solve the elastodynamics equation for a problem with fast scales from an impact (although no shocks).

$\rho\ddot{\mathbf{u}} - \nabla \cdot \sigma(\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{f}$

In structural dynamics, this equation is typically solved with the Newmark scheme with Lagrange elements for the spatial domain discretization. The Newmark scheme is implicit, but I believe given the fast scales, it will be cheaper to solve with an explicit scheme. To avoid inverting the mass matrix from the second-order derivative term, I have seen that a common technique is to lump the mass matrix into a diagonal matrix. What's the accuracy of this technique?

Other methods involve using DG for the spatial discretization, which gives a block diagonal matrix that can be easily inverted, could this be cheaper and more accurate than the above approach? What would be the right way to approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The Newmark method with $\beta=0$, $\gamma=0.5$, with mass lumping, leads to  an explicit scheme.

Comment: My question is how accurate the mass lumping is, specially for unstructured meshes.

Comment: The error due to mass lumping is usually smaller than the discretization error. You can lump safely for most usual applications in both standard finite elements and in DG methods.

Comment: Could you give a reference about your comment please?

Comment: This is discussed in Hughes TJR, "The Finite Element Method", for example.